# Making a refresh button to update ajax in store.js and triggers {#await} promise

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I'm trying to make a refresh button to update the content from a store.js. The store gets the data from a fetch request.

I tried unsubscribing and subscribing but it doesn't seem to work.

The only thing that does refresh the data was making a custom store with refresh action which calls getData() again but it doesn't seem to trigger the promise.

I want to remove the old data and the `Loading...` text to appear every time new data is fetched/refreshed.

How do I go about it? This is what I have so far:

### [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/582fc84627234738a9611095ebe51fd2?version=3.29.7)

```
<script>
  import { testsStore } from './store.js';
    
    let testsStorePromise;
    
    let unsubscribe = testsStore.subscribe(data => {
        testsStorePromise = data;
    });

    function refresh(){
        unsubscribe();
        
        unsubscribe = testsStore.subscribe(data => {
            testsStorePromise = data;
        });
    }        
</script>

<button on:click="{refresh}">Refresh</button>

<h1>
    Todos:
</h1>
{#await testsStorePromise}
<p style="color: blue">LOADING...</p>
{:then todos}

    {#each todos as item}  
        <p>{item.title}</p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}

    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>

{/await}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake seems to be that `testStorePromise` is not actually a promise anymore now, but just the result of the fetch.

One way to solve this is to change your writable store to

```
export const testsStore = writable(getData);
```

and then call this 'value' in your await

```
{#await testsStorePromise()}
```

However if you take the above into consideration, most of your code above is not required anymore, all you need is a simple re-assignment:

```html
<script>
    const apiURL = " https://deelay.me/500/https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    
    // helper to reduce duplication
    const fetchData = fetch(apiURL).then(res => res.json())
    
    // initial fetch
    let testPromise = fetchData
    
    async function refresh() {
        // re-assigning will also restart the promise chain
        testPromise = fetchData
    }
        
</script>
```

Note that now you have a real promise, so you have to use `{#await testPromise}`